# System uses almost all my RAM

Tags: linux, memory, cpu-usage, resource-usage, high-cpu-usage

I am running a Linux Ubuntu(17.10) distro and my system specs are

```
Memory : 7.6 GiB
Processor : Intel® Core™ i5-3210M CPU @ 2.50GHz × 4 
Graphics : Intel® Ivybridge Mobile
GNOME : 3.26.2
OS Type : 64-bit
Disk : 768.7 GB
```

Currently I have `Tilix,Chrome(<6 tabs), PhpStorm` open.
and `npm watch` is compiling my code on the go.

My system usage now are

```
Memory 87% = 6.62/7.6GiB
Swap 15% = 1.13/7.30Gib
```

I have attached the screenshot of `htop`.
What could be the reason of the resource usage?

Memory sort:
[image: Update Screenshot with sort bt RES column]

TOP
[image]

Comment: yes, but I have opened only one. How do I account for the rest of them? Now it is showing more than 2.

Comment: Your screen-shot would be more useful if you sorted by memory

Comment: Added the requested screenshot @AFH

Comment: @HazardousGlitch - By default `htop` shows threads, but reports the same resources as the main program for each thread.

Comment: @Rehan - Sorry I wasn't expecting quite so many threads. Perhaps you could use the `H` and `K` commands to turn off thread reporting (or use `top` which omits threads by default).

Comment: Added the screenshot of the `top`

Comment: Two things: are you using any chrome extensions? If so, list them. And what other instances of Terminal are you running? I suspect it may be your `npm watch`...

Comment: @Rehan just look at your screenshot. You're using over 18% of your system memory on *just* Java. Then another 5% is in use by your terminal emulator.